# Running containers on multiple AWS EC2 instances from docker-compose file

Tags: docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I know it is not possible to run containers on multiple hosts using a single docker-compose file. And this needs something like docker swarm to do it.

Is there anything equivalent to this on AWS - ECS or Fargate?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do this on ECS using EC2 type or using Fargate type cluster.

If you are moving with ECS EC2 Type model you can opt for different task placement strategies for placing your task on different nodes to achieve any model you want like AZ Spread, Binpack etc

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-placement-strategies.html

If you are opting for Fargate ECS Type then you don't have to take care of underlying EC2 nodes as those are managed by AWS in this case.

Also, there is a big difference in docker-compose and docker-swarm.
Docker swarm is the orchestration which is required for your use case as of now.